# How do I start 15 seconds before each video in this filter_complex expression in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have 4 videos basically of 4 people playing together in a coop game. It starts at the same cut scene and then shows each player s screen.

I am trying to merge them together in a 4 x 4 grid with all the videos in sync from the beginning (at all cutscenes) while rest of it goes on usually

I had to take a picture of the cutscene in one of the videos and search for this image to find the offset in each video to sync them up

```
ffmpeg
    -i v_nimble_guardian.mkv -i macko_nimble_guardian.mkv -i ghost_nimble_guardian.mp4 -i nano_nimble_guardian.mkv
    -filter_complex "
        nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [base];
        [0:v] trim=start_pts=59117,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [upperleft];
        [1:v] trim=start_pts=60483,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [upperright];
        [2:v] trim=start_pts=805117,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [lowerleft];
        [3:v] trim=start_pts=48100,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=960x540 [lowerright];
        [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
        [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=960 [tmp2];
        [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=540 [tmp3];
        [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=960:y=540[v]
    "
    -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mkv
```

Everything is in sync perfectly except I would like each video to start 15 seconds before the start_pts frame, how can I specify this?

Like how do I find trim=start_pts=some_value where (you get the idea)

```
some_value = 59117 - 15 seconds
some_value = 805117 - 15 seconds...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simplest maths:

```
new_start_pts = start_pts - ( framerate * 15 )
```

You can get the framerate with:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate video.mp4 | cut -d "/" -f 1
```

Comment: framerate of the output final video i am guessing or each individual video?